# Smart quote issue with sed on a Mac

Tags: linux, macos, sed

Does anyone happen to know why this:

```
echo "random text error: ‘the text I want’" | sed "s%.*error: ‘\(.*\)’%\1%"
```

works like a charm on Linux, but hangs on Mac OS X's implementation of sed. When I say hangs, I mean drops to the next line with no output, and waits.

I know the implementations are different, but cannot seems to find what the specific cause is. I can get Mac OS X's implementation of sed to do other things with smart quotes (such as replace them with "normal" ones).

For anyone who is interested, this is similar to compiler error output. GCC on Mac OS X also outputs smart quotes in its error messages.

Comment: When you say it waits do you get a prompt? Which prompt?

Comment: No, just a blank line. Here are the differences in response: On Linux: drops to the next line and prints: "the text I want" (without the quotes), then drops the next line with the normal shell prompt. I expected that. On a Mac however, it just drops to the next line, no prompt, not even a ">" looking for completion, just a blank line. I have to ctrl-c it.

Comment: Can you break it apart a bit? Try `echo "random text error: ‘the text I want’" | cat` and see if the `echo` on its own piped through a dumb program works okay, then try `echo foo | sed "s%.*error: ‘\(.*\)’%\1%"` to see if `sed` handles the characters well.

Comment: I did indeed try that. In fact I have tried many different ways. Interestingly, if I force a non-match, such as: echo "random text error: ‘the text I want’" | sed "s%.*z\(.*\)%\1%", I am returned the entire string (as expected). It only seems to fail when I match before the "\(.*\)" string. It's driving me a little bonkers, and has become more of a mission now! :-)

Comment: What happens if you press Ctrl-D when it's hung?

Comment: Unlike Ctrl-C, it just returns Ctrl-D and stays in the same state. Repeated Ctrl-Ds causes it do drop a line with each press: ^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^C (Note that in this comment, the newline is not being shown)

Comment: And just for completeness ( :-) ), if I just use normal single quotes as in: echo "random text error: 'the text I want'" | sed "s%.*error: '\(.*\)'%\1%"  ... it works just fine on both platforms. It's something about the use of the smart quotes that is causing it. (I think.)

Comment: I'm betting it's a bug that has to do with the transition from a wide Unicode character to a single-byte ASCII character. Try something like this: `echo 'jalapeño pequeño' | sed 's/.*ñ\(.*\)ño/\1/'`. You should get "o peque".

Comment: Also try: `echo 'è' | sed 's/./x/'` and `echo 'aèa' | sed 's/.\(.\)./\1/'`

Comment: Yes, that hangs too on the Mac, but works on Linux.

Comment: And Perl works nicely in both places: echo "random text error: ‘the text I want’" | perl -pe "s%.*error: ‘(.*)’%\1%"  ... give the correct output "text I want" on both Linux and Mac. I think you are right Dennis, I am willing to file this as an annoying bug unicode support bug.

Comment: Dennis, your last two worked fine (echo 'è' | sed 's/./x/' and echo 'aèa' | sed 's/.\(.\)./\1/'), that is, no hang.

Comment: Are you using the native OS X version of `sed` and not a port? If you can check to see if a bug has been filed on this issue with Apple. For future reference, on SO if you use `@username` a person you are replying to will be automatically notified (as does the owner of a question or answer that a comment is attached to).

Comment: I just tried it with BSD sed on OSX 10.8.2 and it works fine with locale `"en_US.UTF-8"` and with locale `"C"`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you workaround, by putting the sed-command into a file 'quoted.sed', and call it

```
echo "random text error: ‘the text I want’" | sed -f quoted.sed
```

The same problem?